# Where should I save files dynamically generated by the ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My ASP.NET Web API service dynamically generates files for users to download.

The remote application sends a request to the API which:

1. Generates the file and saves it ----> where?? <-----
2. Returns the URL of the file location so it can be downloaded.

Nothing fancy there, but my question is **what are the best practices for where to save these files?**
Some digging around suggests that App_Data might be the appropriate place but I haven't seen anything definitive.

Some considerations:

- This all happens on a company intranet so security isn't really a big deal.
- The files are essentially temporary. Is there a simple way to delete the file once it's downloaded? Not a big deal - I can set up a scheduled task to clean out whatever the destination folder is.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of returning the URL, could you just send the file contents in the response?

Comment: @mbeckish : That's an option too but I do need to be able to return a URL as well.

Comment: Seems to me the return URL would be the same as the initial request URL and simply dynamically generate the file on demand and in memory.

Comment: @mbeckish that's exactly what I wanted to do, but then Apple's Safari doesn't properly support it. It's not even IE this time, although they do have their own implementation to download the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write to any location your application stores data in.

I recommend using the system Temp directory, that's what it's there for (`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`) or if your have write access, a subdirectory of your application:

```
String path = Server.MapPath("~/Temp");
if( !Directory.Exists( path ) ) Directory.CreateDirectory( path );

using(FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite( Path.Combine( path, "TempFileName.dat" ) )) {
    fs.Write( new Byte[1024] );
}
```

Comment: If you use the system Temp directory, how would you know when\how to delete the file?

Comment: On Azure and other (properly configured) web-hosts, the `%TEMP%` directory will be emptied regularly, presumably when they reboot their servers. If it's in your own app subdirectory space you can delete the file after the client has disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your web server, you could also create a virtual directory under your web application and configure it to point to whatever file location you want. Then you can have your application save the files into that virtual directory using System.IO. That's what I've done in the past.